# SQL Server Merge Replication Error - Could not Propagate to the subscriber

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

**I am getting the below Error:**

I have a Publisher SQL Server 2012 on a remote VPS and a local subscriber running on a Parallel VM within Mac.

The Agent at the Publisher has full access to the folder. But is still unable to create the publication db

> Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent SERVER-XXXXX|XXXX
>   failed. The schema script 'tblBankNames_2.sch' could not be propagated
>   to the subscriber.

**Complete Error Message**

> Error messages:
>       The schema script 'tblBankNames_2.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
>       The process could not read file \server\repldata\unc\SERVER_AETDBJ_FMB\20140410103317\tblBankNames_2.sch'
>   due to OS error 5. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
>       Access is denied.
>        (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL5)

Comment: Do you distributor set up?

Comment: Is \server\repldata\unc\ the network share?  Shouldn't it be \\server\repldata\unc?  Notice it should be 2 backslashes before the server name.

Comment: My distributor is set up. I was able to successfully run a merge replication on the same server (Same as the distributor/publisher - Remote VPS). However when i try to run a pull/push replication from my local computer i get that error. I checked the path and i have set it up as //server/repldata/ i think the snaphot agent as well saved data there.

Comment: OS error 5 means "access denied". Recheck the folder permissions.

Comment: I have given all possible users full control on the folder. especially the admin account under which the sql server process is running. Could it be that my local Desktop does not have sufficient permissions to access the replication folders at the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your advise.

It seems like I had a multiple issues with my merge replication

1. I hadn't correctly set up port forwarding on my LAN for incoming connections to correctly read the sql server I logged into my router and set that up after giving my PC a static ip
2. I noticed that I was getting an error when trying to set up the replication from the subscriber so I reversed the process and instead started working from the publisher and set up the replication from there since over there I was able to select the right account permissions with which to run the replicator it worked like a charm and finally I was able to beautifully sync both the server and my local PC over the Internet. Thank god

**It was an access + networking issue**